# Hibernate is preforming updates when its not being told to

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hibernate is doing something I cannot seem to explain. 
I have two entities with the relationship of YearlyBreakDown as many MonthlyBreakdown and a single MonthlyBreakdown has a single YearlyBreakDown.

**What am I seeing?**

When I use hibernate save on the YearlyBreakDown. Hibernate appears to Update the MonthlyBreakdown (See Hibernate logs Below).

**What I know.**

That Hibernate has the ability to Cascade updates, deletes ect. to a child entity but only if the relationship has been defined explicitly, Looking at the annotation documentation, it clearly states that the default is to not cascade operations to its child.

**What I want to happen**

I want to be able to call a hibernate save on my Java Entity without having operations cascaded to the MontlyBreakdown children.

I do not have a deep enough understanding of hibernate to know if I've set something up incorrectly, I'm wondering if anyone can explain what is happening or point out something I'm doing incorrectly.

YearlyBreakDown.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "YRLY_BRKDN", schema = "pricing")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQ_YRLY_BRKDN_ID", name = "SEQ_YRLY_BRKDN_ID", schema = "pricing", allocationSize = 1)
public class YearlyBreakdown {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_YRLY_BRKDN_ID")
        @Column(name = "YRLY_BRKDN_ID")
        @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
        private Integer                     id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "yearlyBreakdown")
        private List<MonthBreakdown>        monthBreakdowns  = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

MontlyBreakdown.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MTH_BRKDN", schema = "pricing")
public class MonthBreakdown implements Processable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MTH_BRKDN_ID")
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Integer                  id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "YRLY_BRKDN_ID")
    private ServiceOfferingBreakdown serviceOfferingBreakdown;

    @Column(name = "MTH_CT")
    private Integer                  month;

    @Column(name = "DRCT_CST_AM")
    private BigDecimal               directCost;

    @Column(name = "RISK_CST_AM")
    private BigDecimal               riskCost;

    @Column(name = "INFLTN_CST_AM")
    private BigDecimal               inflationCost;

    @Column(name = "NET_REV_AM")
    private BigDecimal               netRevenue;

    @Column(name = "GRS_MRGN_AM")
    private BigDecimal               grossMargin;

    @Column(name = "OPER_PRFT_AM")
    private BigDecimal               operatingProfit;

    @Transient
    private boolean                  processed;

}
```

Hibernate Logs

```
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: select monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_0_, monthbreak0_.MTH_BRKDN_ID as MTH_BRKD1_1_1_, monthbreak0_.DRCT_CST_AM as DRCT_CST2_1_1_, monthbreak0_.GRS_MRGN_AM as GRS_MRGN3_1_1_, monthbreak0_.INFLTN_CST_AM as INFLTN_C4_1_1_, monthbreak0_.MTH_CT as MTH_CT5_1_1_, monthbreak0_.NET_REV_AM as NET_REV_6_1_1_, monthbreak0_.OPER_PRFT_AM as OPER_PRF7_1_1_, monthbreak0_.RISK_CST_AM as RISK_CST8_1_1_, monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID as SRVC_OFR9_1_1_ from pricing.MTH_BRKDN monthbreak0_ where monthbreak0_.YRLY_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
Hibernate: update pricing.MTH_BRKDN set DRCT_CST_AM=?, GRS_MRGN_AM=?, INFLTN_CST_AM=?, MTH_CT=?, NET_REV_AM=?, OPER_PRFT_AM=?, RISK_CST_AM=? where MTH_BRKDN_ID=?
```

Comment: add the transactional method in which you perform the save

Comment: The default cascade trategy of hibernte is `no operations are cascaded.` if you don't understand it, nevermind. IMHO everthing is done correctly, if you are curious on what happend you can profile your DB query depends on which DB you are using, you will see what happened exact there.